# Как объединить колонки таблицы, которые ячейками соотносятся как 2к3?

Tags: html, css, css3, table, span

А именно, надо из этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сделать вот это [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без учёта стилей. То есть надо просто объединить ячейки. Код не присылаю, потому что нужна лишь общая инструкция по объединению. Полностью. Такой в поиске нет. Без флексов. Только способностями табличек. Граница между этими двумя словами должна быть.

Comment: Есть такая инфа в инете, colspan, rowspan, как-то так называется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Просверлим</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">до</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>      
      <td rowspan="2">все</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>20мм</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```